# Como alterar o volume de um video <iframe> pelo javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

Tenho tentado o código abaixo para resolver.

```
var volumeIcon = 1;

$(".ico-volume").on('click', function(event) {

   if (volumeIcon == 1)
   {
      $(this).find("img").removeAttr('src');
      $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'img/ico/volume-out-ico.png');
      volumeIcon = 0;
      setVolume(volumeIcon);
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).find("img").removeAttr('src');
      $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'img/ico/volume-in-ico.png');
      volumeIcon = 1;
      setVolume(volumeIcon);
   }

});

essa primeira função é de um icone de volume que eu tenho aqui, e quando o usuário apertar ele troca a imagem, mas se atentem na função que ele chama por ultimo. Pois bem, aqui vai as outras funções:

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId)
{
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("video");  
}

function setVolume(volume)
{
    if (ytplayer)
        ytplayer.volume = volume;
}
```

**Obs:** No HTML do player, já coloquei o parâmetro no `enablejsapi=1` no `<iframe>`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor? :D

Comment: Bom, pelo jeito que meu código saiu já deu pra ver que é a primeira vez que posto aqui. kkkkkkkk
Me desculpem por isso. Se alguém souber me falar como posto um código aqui também eu agradeço! ^^

Comment: de onde vem o video Youtube?

Comment: @CaioChaim Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, seria interessante dá uma lida no tour http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para saber como funciona o site.

Comment: Valeu Marconi, pela dica! =D

sim Danilo, esqueci de mencionar, é do Youtube sim!

Comment: Você está incorporando o iframe?. Por exemplo: <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PearQPnNzEE?list=WL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: isso, isso mesmo! :)

Answer (score 2):

Dei uma pesquisada aqui na API do Youtube e veja o que encontrei:

**Desativa o som do player.**

```
player.mute():Void
```

**Ativa o som do player.**

```
player.unMute():Void
```

**Retorna true se o player estiver no mudo. Em caso negativo, retorna false.**

```
player.isMuted():Boolean
```

**Define o volume. Aceita um número inteiro entre 0 e 100.**

> Isso que você tem que fazer no seu código.

```
player.setVolume(volume:Number):Void
```

**Retorna o volume atual do player, um número inteiro entre 0 e 100. getVolume() retornará o volume mesmo se o player estiver no mudo.**

```
player.getVolume():Number
```

Segue o Link da API do YouTube.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=pt-br